# React router: How to render two different components on different pages?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am building a react app. I am using react-router-dom V4.

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Route path='/' component={TodoComponent}></Route>
                    <Route path='/about' component={About}></Route>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

How can I render these two different components on different pages? This is how the output looks:

[TodoReact APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeVPW.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `exact` attribute to your root `/` route, currently both routes match `/about`, so both components will show:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={TodoComponent} />
```

Comment: Glad to help! :-)

Comment: Does this work the same for Route Links?? I mean I am getting two route links on the same component. How to avoid it and get one route link on one page to switch between components